# Refresh opener of opener window after the immediate opener window had been closed

Tags: javascript, html, window, reload, page-refresh

Lets assume, `WindowA` pops up `WindowB`.

Then `WindowB` pops up `WindowC`.

After opening `windowC`, `WindowB` is closed automatically.

Is there any way in `Javascript` to **refresh/reload** `WindowA` from `WindowC`, provided that it's (WindowC's) opener window (`WindowB`) has been closed? 
Or it is impossible since `WindowC.opener` will return `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that via keeping reference of `WindowA` in `WindowC`.

upon loading `windowC`or (whatever operation you do)

```
superParrent= window.opener.opener;
```

then even if you close `WindowB` you can reload.

```
superParrent.location.reload();
```

The things is you have to initialize var `superParrent` before closing `WindowB`